# Is there a way to put an object in two different places in an array and have them have different values?

Tags: javascript

I am making a small game in JavaScript to help me learn it. The game is based around an array of tiles, each with different values.

When it starts, it puts an object into each cell, then goes on to the next, changing the values.

It always shows the properties of the last cell. Is there any way I can have the cells have different values without making tons of different objects?

Sorry if the question isn't clear. I'm very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @ImTryingMyBest - please include some example code, it'll make it easier to give advice.

Comment: You have to make "tons of different objects".  Don't worry about it, JavaScript is good at that.

Comment: thanks @pointy, i was just trying to see if there was a different way.

Comment: Is there any snippet you can share to see how your code is structured in relation to the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the objects and there is few ways to declare array and work with it.  You can follow the javascript [doucemntation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

If you are not satisfy the documentation there is some array examples to understand the value changing and objects changing.

1. JavaScript Array: [Explained with uses in different components](https://www.jquery-az.com/javascript-array-explained-with-uses-in-different-components/)
2. JavaScript [Pass By Value And Pass By Reference In JavaScript](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c)
3. JavaScript Arrays - [tips, tricks and examples](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6181/javascript-arrays---tips-tricks-and-examples)

If you have any question comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pushing the same object over and over into the array. Use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to essentially clone the object in place while changing the values you need.

```js
const array = []
const obj = { a: 5, b: 6 };

array.push(obj);
array.push(obj);
obj.b = 8;

array.push({ ...obj, b: 10 })

console.log(array[0], array[1], array[2]);
```

As you see, `obj.b=8` affects both the first and second elements of the arrays as they are both referring to the same object. But since the spread  (`...`) operator is cloning the object, only the last element has `b=10`